# Pencil touch not recognized after finger touch

Tags: touch, uitouch, apple-pencil

I'm working on a sketch app, and I'm pretty happy with it so far. Palm rejection works well by checking if the touch type is `.pencil`. However, when I draw, I sometimes use my pinky finger instead of my palm. In this case, I'm not getting the pencil touch.

If I print out all the touches from `touchesBegan` and `touchesMoved` I see only the finger touch. I don't do any further processing with the touches if a pencil is not detected. But I expect a new touch to be added when I press the pencil after I've pressed with my finger. Is that a wrong expectation? If so, how should I handle this?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out all I had to do was set `isMultipleTouchEnabled` to true.